# How to take two entries

Tags: pine-script

```
    //@version=4
strategy("three OutSide Bar Strategy", overlay=true)

target = 3400
sl=9000
if (close > open and close[1] > open[1] and close[2]>open[2] and hour>= 12 and hour <19)// or hour ==20)
    strategy.entry("OutBarLE", strategy.long, comment="OutBarLE")
    strategy.exit("exit","OutBarLE",profit=target,loss=sl)


if (close < open and close[1] < open[1] and close[2] < open[2] and hour>= 12 and hour <19)// or hour ==20)
    strategy.entry("OutBarSE", strategy.short, comment="OutBarLE")
    strategy.exit("exit","OutBarSE",profit=target,loss=sl)
```

I have tried a basic strategy and i see that if there is a open position the it is not entering another position. It takes the position only after the already open position closed.

for Example if a position is open in the ID OutBarLE and the same condition occurs when the position is open the condition is not validated since the position is open. How to handle two or more position at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `Pyramiding` to a value that's greater than 1 in the strategy settings.
You can read about pyramiding here:

- [TradingView - Strategies](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html)
- [Kodify.net - How to set a TradingView strategy's pyramiding with code?](https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/strategy-pyramiding/)
- [BackTestRookies - Tradingview: Pyramiding](https://backtest-rookies.com/2018/08/17/tradingview-pyramiding/)

You can also [search StackOverflow for Pyramiding within the [pine-script] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpine-script%5D%20pyramiding) to find more examples.